# error when plotting a fitted line of normal distribution in r

Tags: r

I tried to plot a fitted line of a normal distribution using lines() function in R but it generates an error. The data is SP500 and I am trying to compare the distribution of log return of SP500 with a normal distribution with calculated mean and standard deviation.

```
SP500_R = diff(log(SP500['2008/2009']))

# compare the log return with normal distribution using dnorm function
mu = mean(SP500_R, na.rm=T)
sigma = sd(SP500_R, na.rm=T)

hist(SP500_R, nclass = 20, probability = TRUE)
lines(SP500_R, dnorm(SP500_R, mean = mu, sd = sigma), col='red', lend = 2)
```

I thought it was the problem of NA in SP500_R but it turned out that it was not the problem. The error is the same after deleting the NA in SP500_R. After restarting R, the error changed into the second one.

I expected a plot with a histogram and a red line, but I got an error like this:

```
Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : 
  graphical parameter "lend" has the wrong length
```

The second error after restarting R:

```
Error in get(".xts_chob", .plotxtsEnv) : object '.xts_chob' not found
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about SP500 object? Can you give the output of `str(SP500)`? Is it a named vector or a dataframe?

Comment: SP500 is an xts object and the SP500_R is also an xts object.  Here is the output ```An ‘xts’ object on 1950-01-03/2015-12-31 containing:
  Data: num [1:16607, 1] 16.7 16.9 16.9 17 17.1 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "^GSPC"
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
 $ src    : chr "yahoo"
 $ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2016-01-03 10:42:11"```

Comment: I'm having trouble replicating this.  We really need a [mcve], please.  It should probably be sufficient to edit your question to paste in the output of `dput(head(SP500_R,20))` .

Comment: The data is downloaded using ``` data('SP500') ``` from qrmdata package. I think you could reproduce by adding the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(xts)

set.seed(12345)
SP500 <- xts(x=rnorm(500, mean=50), order.by=Sys.Date()-(1:500)*30)
SP500 ['2008/2009']

SP500_R = diff(log(SP500['2008/2009']))

head(SP500_R)
#                     [,1]
# 2008-01-22            NA
# 2008-02-21  0.0107095178
# 2008-03-22 -0.0337194554
# 2008-04-21 -0.0007512932
# 2008-05-21  0.0729341823
# 2008-06-20 -0.0757315444


# compare the log return with normal distribution using dnorm function
mu = mean(SP500_R, na.rm=T)
sigma = sd(SP500_R, na.rm=T)

#Remove first row and plot the result
lx <- as.numeric(SP500_R[-1])
hist(lx, nclass = 20, probability = TRUE)
lines(density(lx), col="red", lend=2, lwd=2)
```

[image]

Using dnorm() function to display the line:

```
lx <- as.numeric(SP500_R[-1]) 
h<- hist(lx, nclass = 20, probability = TRUE) 
lines(sort(lx), dnorm(lx[order(lx)], mean = mu, sd = sigma), lend = 2, col='red', lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was able to plot the density line using your code. However, I am still having trouble with the dnorm line.  
lx=as.numeric(SP500_R)  
hist(lx, nclass = 20, probability = TRUE) 
lines(lx, dnorm(SP500_R, mean = mu, sd = sigma), lend = 2, col='red') 
, but the plot generated was wild. If I use lines(dnorm(SP500_R, mean = mu, sd = sigma), lend = 2, col='red') , there was no error but also no fitted line shown on the plot.

Comment: @zihanchen I added an alternative solution using dnorm() function